# How to push the tasklist into an array with the add button?

Tags: javascript

The `function addTask()` is the function that when the user clicks the "+" button it adds the list to the array. I have a render function that renders the to-do list when the "+" is added. I sat and thought about how I could do this.

doing the ```` taskList.push()``` in the ```function addTask()``` might work, but the issue I am having is I am not sure how to push the elements of the  ```function renderList(list)``` into the ```` taskList.push()```.

I am missing something in this approach, but I am not sure what. I know I need to access the ```let newtask```` and add that bit to the array.

HTML

```
 <div class="form">
        <input class ="user-input" type="text">
        <input class="date" type="date">
        <input class="time" type="time">
        <button onclick="addTask()" class="add" id="add">+</button>
    </div>

    <div class="list"></div>
```

JS

```
//local storage key
const STORAGE_KEY = "tasks-storage-key";

// variables object
const el = {
  form: document.querySelector(".form"),
  input: document.querySelector(".user-input"),
  list: document.querySelector(".list"),
  date: document.querySelector(".date"),
  time: document.querySelector(".time"),
};

//Create ID

const createId = () =>
  `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)}${new Date().getTime()}`;

//variable of empty array that gets new task
let taskList = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY) ?? "[]");

function makeNewTask() {
  const data = {
    id: createId(),
    taskNew: el.input.value,
    taskDate: el.date.value,
    taskTime: el.time.value,
  };

  return data;
}

//function that creates new tasks with date and time
function display() {
   data = makeNewTask();
   taskList.push(data); 
   renderList(taskList); 
   storeList();
}

function renderList(list) {
  list.forEach(function (data) {
    const tasks = document.createElement("div");
    let newtask = (tasks.innerHTML = `
         <div class="task-content">
          <div class="task" data-id="${data.id}">
          <div class="new-task-created">${data.taskNew}</div>
          <label class="due-date">${data.taskDate}</label>
          <label class="due-time">${data.taskTime}</label>
      </div>
  
      <div class="action-buttons">
          <button onclick="editItem(event)" class="edit" data-id="${data.id}">Edit</button>
          <button onclick="deleteItem(event)" class="delete" data-id="${data.id}">Delete</button>
          <button onclick="completeItem(event)" class="complete" data-id="${data.id}">Complete</button>
      </div>
  </div>`);
    el.list.appendChild(tasks);
  });
}

//event listner that listens for add button.
function addTask() {
   taskList.push(list);
}

//function that stores task list.
function storeList() {
  window.localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(taskList));
}

//function that removes task from array with delete button.

function deleteItem() {
  let removeitem = document.querySelector(".task-content");
  removeitem.parentNode.removeChild(removeitem);
  window.localStorage.removeItem(STORAGE_KEY);
}

//function that removes stored task when deleted.

//function that that edits tasks with date and time.
function editItem() {}

//function that that completes task.
function completeItem(event) {
  const element = event.target.closest(".task-content");
  console.log(element);
  let taskItem = element.querySelector(".new-task-created");
  let dateItem = element.querySelector(".due-date");
  let timeItem = element.querySelector(".due-time");
  // style..
  taskItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
  dateItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
  timeItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
}
```

This is the error I get.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code, but let's start with the error:

Well the issue is that `addTask` function does not receive a `list` parameter that you are trying to push. I think you want to call `makeNewTask()` there instead of passing that `list` that is `undefined`.

```js
  //event listner that listens for add button.
  function addTask() {
     taskList.push(makeNewTask());
  }
```

The next problem is that `display()` is never called. Also, why are you creating an empty task when calling display? The display function is redundant, you should only call `renderList(taskList)`. You should call `storeList()` only when it changes (creation of new task or removal of one).

Next problem is in your `renderList()` function. You are assigning that `newTask` variable that you never actually use. Also if you're appending children to the main element in a `forEach` on that `list`, it will keep adding new lists of elements. I don't think you want that.

```js
function renderList() {
    el.list.innerHTML = taskList.map(function (data) {
        return `<div class="task">
            <div class="task-content">
                <div class="task" data-id="${data.id}">
                <div class="new-task-created">${data.taskNew}</div>
                <label class="due-date">${data.taskDate}</label>
                <label class="due-time">${data.taskTime}</label>
            </div>
    
            <div class="action-buttons">
                <button onclick="editItem(event)" class="edit" data-id="${data.id}">Edit</button>
                <button onclick="deleteItem(event)" class="delete" data-id="${data.id}">Delete</button>
                <button onclick="completeItem(event)" class="complete" data-id="${data.id}">Complete</button>
            </div>
        </div>`;
    });
}
```

Also, `renderList` should use the `taskList` instead of receiving a `list` parameter since you're already storing the `taskList` globally (which is not great either).

The final working code should be something like this (added some comments as well -- I suggest using classes for structuring your data but I'll leave that up to you):

```js
//local storage key
const STORAGE_KEY = "tasks-storage-key";

// variables object
const el = {
    form: document.querySelector(".form"),
    input: document.querySelector(".user-input"),
    list: document.querySelector(".list"),
    date: document.querySelector(".date"),
    time: document.querySelector(".time"),
};

//Create ID

const createId = () => `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)}${new Date().getTime()}`;

//variable of empty array that gets new task
let taskList = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY) ?? "[]");

// This should be called initially after you read the data from localstorage in order to display the initial data if you have any.
renderList();

function makeNewTask() {
    const data = {
        id: createId(),
        taskNew: el.input.value,
        taskDate: el.date.value,
        taskTime: el.time.value,
    };

    return data;
}

function renderList() {
    // actually reset the list innerHTML to the new list (in order to facilitate removing / adding -- not very efficient)
    el.list.innerHTML = taskList.map(function (data) {
        return `<div class="task">
            <div class="task-content">
                <div class="task" data-id="${data.id}">
                <div class="new-task-created">${data.taskNew}</div>
                <label class="due-date">${data.taskDate}</label>
                <label class="due-time">${data.taskTime}</label>
            </div>
    
            <div class="action-buttons">
                <button onclick="editItem(event)" class="edit" data-id="${data.id}">Edit</button>
                <button onclick="deleteItem(event)" class="delete" data-id="${data.id}">Delete</button>
                <button onclick="completeItem(event)" class="complete" data-id="${data.id}">Complete</button>
            </div>
        </div>`;
    });
}

//event listner that listens for add button.
function addTask() {
    taskList.push(makeNewTask());
    // store the list on localstorage because data changed
    storeList();
    // render list again because you've added a new entry
    renderList();
}

//function that removes task from array with delete button.
function deleteItem(event) {
    taskList.splice(taskList.indexOf(event.target.dataset.id), 1);
    // store the list on localstorage because data changed
    storeList();
    // render list again because you've removed an entry
    renderList();
}

//function that stores task list.
function storeList() {
    window.localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(taskList));
}

//function that that edits tasks with date and time.
function editItem() { }

//function that that completes task.
function completeItem(event) {
    const element = event.target.closest(".task-content");
    let taskItem = element.querySelector(".new-task-created");
    let dateItem = element.querySelector(".due-date");
    let timeItem = element.querySelector(".due-time");
    // style..
    taskItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    dateItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    timeItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
}
```

I'd like to add that since `completeItem` function only changes the current DOM, it cannot be stored on `localStorage` so on refresh you won't know which tasks are completed. I would suggest adding a property `completed` to each `taskList` entry so you can recreate the `completed` state when refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

as it was mentioned by Cristian the error that you are getting is because the function is not receiving the parameter ‘list’, you can simply try to put this instead:

```
function addTask() {
  display();
}
```

Then you should see the task on the UI but there are more things that you will need to improve related with your code logic